# Amazon Lambda use cases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to make some kind of HTTP request that will trigger Lambda and allow it to build a response for the request?

Is it possible for Lambda to access CloudFront cache directly or somehow get the data it needs. I guess it can be done making HTTP requests to CloudFront, but maybe there is more direct way to do that, no?

Or all this stuff I'm asking here is a peace of **** and I better go and buy a new server or optimize my code (actually, i would like to, but manager wants CloudFront + Lambda, so I'm trying to figure out if that is possible, but the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/use-cases.html) don't give me an answer. Am I blind maybe?)

Comment: if you are using python27 or python36, python37 you may want to look at chalice or zappa(better for me). It will do a lot of the connections between the Lambda, Route53,  CloudFront

Answer (score 3):

You can expose your lambda function via an API gateway. Then your lambda function can just run code that will access other services/resources (CloundFront, SNS, SQS, etc). Use the AWS SDK to access these services.

See Amazon API Gateway documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Comment: Precisely. API Gateway uses CloudFront. I was just responding with the same answer haha